# SQL QUESTION_Case When + LIKE %

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, query, like, case-sensitive

I get an error but I don´t understand why.
Does this make sense in SQL?

I need the column `ValidNaming` to be filled with False/True if the customer (or field `CommonLastName`) has an invalid name.

Why this is not working?

```
Select
CommonLastName,
CASE COMMONLASTNAME
     WHEN ((CommonLastName like 'Connect%')
     OR (CommonLastName = 'Unknown', '', 'Null')) THEN 'False'
     ELSE 'True'
END ValidNaming,
FROM [DA1]
```

:( Thanks for any help

Comment: Please edit the question and include the error too. Is it an error message? Wrong results?

Answer (score 1):

You have several syntax error in there

You mix-up `simple case` and `search case` syntax. Do refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

The expression is `CommonLastName = 'Unknown', '', 'Null'` You can't check for multiple match like that. Use `IN ( . . . )` . Also you need to use `IS NULL` when checking for `NULL` value

There is an extra comma after `ValidNaming`

---

Corrected query

```
Select
       CommonLastName,
       CASE WHEN CommonLastName like 'Connect%'
            OR   CommonLastName IN ('Unknown', '') 
            OR   CommonLastName IS NULL
            THEN 'False'
            ELSE 'True'
       END ValidNaming
FROM   [DA1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help  Friend! <3